# Building an instant-forwarding function for mu4e

Tags: mu4e

I am using `mu4e`. I would like to have a function that I can call from the headers view and that instantly (after asking for confirmation) forwards the currently selected mail to a set of addresses. This is my first attempt:

```lisp
(setq my-recipients "mail1@foo.bar,mail2@foo.bar")
(defun mail-instant-forward ()
    (interactive)
    ""
    (mu4e-compose-forward)
    (message-goto-to)
    (insert my-recipients)
    (let ((answer (y-or-n-p "Letse go? ")))
        (when (eq answer 't)
            (message-send-and-exit))
        ))
```

This actually seems straightforward to me: Open the 'compose' buffer with the forwarded mail, set the point to the 'To:' field, insert the addresses from `my-recipients`, and send. Basically what I would do manually.

If I call this function with a header selected, I get the same as if I only called `mu4e-compose-forward` (e.g. by pressing `F` in the headers view). No addresses are inserted, and I'm not being asked if I want to send the mail. My `*Messages*` buffer shows:

```
message-position-on-field: Search failed: "^--text follows this line--$"
```

That is an error in a call inside `message-goto-to`. Actually I might be able to skip the call to `message-goto-to`, since the 'To:' header field is by default selected after a call to `mu4e-compose-forward`. If I remove the `message-goto-to` call from the function, I get this error in `*Messages*`:

```
mail-instant-forward: Buffer is read-only: #<buffer *mu4e-headers*>
```

This looks like after a call to `mu4e-compose-forward`, the buffer with the new email is not the current buffer, right? That feels wrong, since if I call `mu4e-compose-forward` directly, I end up typing in the respective buffer. I now suspect that the function `mu4e-compose-forward` returns before the actual compose buffer exists and is the current buffer. Some asynchroneous magic seems to be happening there.

Now I'm at a loss. Is there some way for me to "wait" in my function until the ansynchroneous operation has completed and the current buffer is the compose buffer? I don't know the buffer's name in advance, since it contains the mail's subject. Can I place a hook on "something" that runs once the buffer is ready?

Comment: To answer your last question, yes, you can use `mu4e-compose-mode-hook`, so maybe one solution is to save the original hook as a local variable, add what you want to do to the hook, run `mu4e-compose-forward`, `(sit-for 1)`, and then revert the hook to its original value using setq.

Comment: Hi @jagrg, thanks for the suggestion. I thought about that and it has the disadvantage that if anything unforseen happens and the `mu4e-compose-mode-hook` is not run, I mess up things and the next mail I compose gets instantly sent to my mailing list. So if at all possible I would like to avoid that.

Comment: `mu4e-compose-forward` is a wrapper,  it ends calling `mu4e~compose-handler`  (or whatever is defined in `mu4e-compose-func`). The only way to get into header manipulation the way you want is IMHO using the compose hooks checking for your own conditions from there and then possibly hook into your own code for sending.